# How to clean up Docker ZFS legacy shares

Tags: docker, zfs, volumes

### Summary

Given that:

- The storage driver `docker` users is ZFS;
- Only `docker` creates `legacy` datasets;

Bash:

```
$ docker ps -a | wc -l
16

$ docker volume ls | wc -l
12

$ zfs list | grep legacy | wc -l
157
```

16 containers (both running and stopped). 12 volumes. **157 datasets.** This seems like an awful lot of legacy datasets. I'm wondering if a lot of them are so orphaned that not even `docker` knows about them anymore, so they don't get cleaned up.

### Rationale

There is a huge list of legacy volumes in my Debian zfs pool. They started appearing when I started using Docker on this machine:

```
$ sudo zfs list | grep legacy | wc -l
486
```

They are all in the form of:

```
pool/var/<64-char-hash>                  202K  6,18T   818M  legacy
```

This location is used solely by docker.

```
$ docker info | grep -e Storage -e Dataset
Storage Driver: zfs
 Parent Dataset: pool/var
```

I started cleaning up.

```
$ docker system prune -a
  (...)
$ sudo zfs list | grep legacy | wc -l
154
```

That's better. However, I'm only running about 15 containers, and after running `docker system prune -a`, the history or every container shows that only the last image layer is still available. The rest are `<missing>` (because they are cleaned up).

```
$ docker images | wc -l
15
```

If all containers use only the last image layer after pruning the rest, **shouldn't docker only use 15 image layers and 15 running containers, totalling 30 volumes?**

```
$ sudo zfs list | grep legacy | wc -l
154
```

Can I find out if they are in use by a container/image? Is there a command that traverses all `pool/var/<hash>` datasets in ZFS and figures out to what docker container/image they belong? Either a lot of them can be removed, or I don't understand how to figure out (beyond just trusting `docker system prune`) they cannot.

The excessive use of zfs volumes by docker messes up my `zfs list` command, both visually and performance-wise. Listing zfs volumes now takes ~10 seconds in stead of <1.

#### Proof that docker sees no more dangling counts

```
$ docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited"
  (no output)
$ docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc
  (no output)
$ docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
  (no output)
```

---

`zfs list` example:

```
NAME                                                                                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
pool                                                                                      11,8T  5,81T   128K  /pool
pool/var                                                                                   154G  5,81T   147G  /mnt/var
pool/var/0028ab70abecb2e052d1b7ffc4fdccb74546350d33857894e22dcde2ed592c1c                 1,43M  5,81T  1,42M  legacy
pool/var/0028ab70abecb2e052d1b7ffc4fdccb74546350d33857894e22dcde2ed592c1c@211422332       10,7K      -  1,42M  -
# and 150 more of the last two with different hashes
```

Comment: Have you tried the instructions suggested here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655849/how-to-see-which-docker-volume-is-or-was-being-used-by-which-container

Comment: I did now, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't work for finding what mounts are used for images or layers. It only finds containers with certain _volumes_, e.g. the ones in `docker volume ls` - which are only about 15 volumes (as expected)

Comment: I did read your question over 10 times. Then I realized maybe you didn't mean volumes in Docker at all. Since volumes in docker cannot appear from air, we must specify them by '-v' flag. Could u plz put piece of content of 'sudo zfs list'? May be I should edit my answer below after that...

Comment: @Light.G They are most probably _also_ Docker layers, because of the `zfs` storage driver. But I'm suspecting they are orphaned from an ancient version. See example output edited at the end of the question.

Comment: @Redsandro I don’t have experience on Docker with zfs. But I am wandering if the mountpoint are legacy when you run a container? Or somehow it got changed later?

Comment: @Redsandro: Can confirm the behavoir with the lastest Docker, did the prune dance, looks like a (yet another) bug in Docker :/ 

This worked (but kills all volumes/images/etc.pp) for Docker: `zfs list -r rpool/docker | awk '/docker\// { print $1 }' | xargs -l zfs destroy -R`

Replace `rpool/docker` with your local Docker dataset.

Comment: Things become additionally difficult when running `zfs-auto-snapshot`, as all those many ZFS datasets created by Docker get additionally snapshotted regularly. Not sure yet if I like that. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same question but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Adding [what I eventually found](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/d0nlbu/docker_with_zfs_root_why_is_it_making_so_many/ezaxnib/), since this question is one of the top search results.

## Background

The ZFS storage driver for Docker stores **each layer of each image** as a separate legacy dataset.

Even just a handful of images can result in a huge number of layers, each layer corresponding to a `legacy` ZFS dataset.

- Quote from the [Docker ZFS driver docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/#image-layering-and-sharing):

  > The base layer of an image is a ZFS filesystem. Each child layer is a ZFS clone based on a ZFS snapshot of the layer below it. A container is a ZFS clone based on a ZFS Snapshot of the top layer of the image it’s created from.

## Investigate

You can check the datasets used by one image by running:

```sh
 $ docker image inspect [IMAGE_NAME]
```

Example output:

```
...
"RootFS": {
    "Type": "layers",
    "Layers": [
        "sha256:f2cb0ecef392f2a630fa1205b874ab2e2aedf96de04d0b8838e4e728e28142da",
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "sha256:2e8cc9f5313f9555a4decca744655ed461e21fbe48a0f078ed5f7c4e5292ad2e",
    ]
},
...
```

This explains why you can see 150+ datasets created when only running a dozen containers.

## Solution

1. Prune and delete unused images.

   ```
   $ docker image prune -a
   ```
2. To avoid a slow `zfs list`, specify the dataset of interest.
   Suppose you store docker in `tank/docker` and other files in `tank/data`. List only the `data` datasets by the recursive option:

   ```
   # recursively list tank/data/*
   $ zfs list tank/data -r
   ```

Comment: I created a small python tool that lists zfs datasets as a tree, with used size, and snapshots laid out in boxes. It helped me clean up that kind of mess. At least I could visualise it. https://github.com/vizyon-sa/zfs-tree

Answer (score 2):

I use docker-in-docker containers that also generates a lot of unused snapshot.

based on @Redsandro comment I've used the following command

```
sudo zfs list -t snapshot -r pool1| wc -l
sudo zpool list

(sudo zfs get  mounted |grep "mounted   no" | awk '/docker\// { print $1 }' |  xargs -l sudo zfs destroy -R ) 2> /dev/null
```

as just delete all snapshot ruined the consistency of docker.
But as docker mounts all images that uses under /var/lib/docker/zfs/graph
(same for the docker-in-docker images) so ignoring those that mounted only should delete dangling images/volumes/containers that was not properly freed up. You need to run this till the number of snapshot decreasing.

Comment: So... this removes zfs snapshots, but does not remove layers in docken registry, and now I have to fix our docker host. 
Well at least I freed up 500GB of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

[Prune introductions](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) on docker.com.

I assume your docker version is lower than V17.06. Since you’ve executed `docker system prune -a`, the old layers’ building information and volumes are missing. And `-a/--all` flag means all images without at least one container would be deleted. Without `-a/--all` flag, just dangling images would be deleted.

In addition, I think you have misunderstanding about `<missing>` mark and dangling images. `<missing>` doesn't mean that the layers marked as missing are really missing. It just means that these layers may be built on other machines. Dangling images are non-referenced images. Even the name and tag are marked `<none>`, the image still could be referenced by other images, which could check with `docker history image_id`.

In your case, these layers are marked as missing, since you have deleted the old versions of images which include building information. You said above--only latest version images are available--thus, only the latest layer are not marked missing.

Note this: `docker system prune` is a lazy way to manage all objects(image/container/volume/network/cache) of Docker.

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. However, `system prune` implies `volume prune` so I already did that. Just to be sure, I did a `volume prune`. It returns _"Total reclaimed space: 0B"._

Comment: @Redsandro Aha yes, so far it seems no undo operation for `system prune`. Next time, try `volume prune` instead.